# Big Commerce Dropdown responsiveness issue

Tags: responsive, bigcommerce

I've come across a bug on some of my product pages on my bigcommerce store. 
It seems like the Size  box is not responsive or not clickable when viewed on phones or a width below 850px.

https://mbstonecare.com/mb-15-stone-glow/

I'm mostly having trouble finding the element in the code editor. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the size buttons are clickable now on mobile...are you still seeing the issue on your end?

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! I was still seeing the same issue so I changed the size selection from a dropdown to rectangular boxes which happen to be clickable on both.